# Redirect to url with Laravel

Tags: redirect, laravel, return, message

I have a little problem with laravel, more precisely with the redirect. Locally all is well while online happens: If, for example, I click on "Exit" to log out, does not go directly to the pages of the log but appears a totally white page where it says "Redirecting to url" and then the login page. There is the possibility to hide this jump and this intermediate page? What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
return Redirect::to('login');
```

Comment: The the page say "Redirecting or url" or does your *browser* display this message?

Comment: Browse, but only when I try the code online, when I try the code in local it work

Comment: This is no bug. Every redirect causes a white page until the new page loads. The difference between local and your server is probably that on localhost the page loads much faster.

Comment: And there is another type of code to prevent it happening?

Comment: Not really. The only thing to prevent a page reload would be write a single page javascript application that communicates with the server via ajax. Otherwise you will always have the white flicker. (The length of it depending on the speed of your internet connection and server response time)

Answer (score 0):

Then the problem is in your code. When you click logout it should just go to your function for log out, and  then that function should redirect you to your home page.

Or maybe you are using named routes in Laravel

```
Example: Route::get('/home' , ['as' => 'home-page', 'uses' => 'homeController@login'])
```

Redirect::to is not for named routes.

`Redirect::route('home-page)` is for named routes, maybe you mixed up your routes.